# Unable to return command line args from function

Tags: rust

I am trying to make a simple function to return the command line arguments. Code looks like this:

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let (query, filename) = parse();
}

fn parse() -> (&str, &str) {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let query = args[1];
    let filename = args[2];

    return (query, filename)
}
```

However it will not compile, the errors look like this:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> src/main.rs:15:22
   |
15 | fn parse() -> (&str, &str) {
   |                      ^ help: consider giving it a 'static lifetime: `&'static`
   |
   = help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but there is no value for it to be borrowed from
```

It suggests that I need to add `&'static` to the function declaration, like this:

```
fn parse() -> (&'static str, &'static str) {
```

But that does not work either;

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:20:13
   |
20 |     return (query, filename)
   |             ^^^^^
   |             |
   |             expected reference, found struct `std::string::String`
   |             help: consider borrowing here: `&query`
   |
   = note: expected type `&'static str`
              found type `std::string::String`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:20:20
   |
20 |     return (query, filename)
   |                    ^^^^^^^^
   |                    |
   |                    expected reference, found struct `std::string::String`
   |                    help: consider borrowing here: `&filename`
   |
   = note: expected type `&'static str`
              found type `std::string::String`
```

It says I need to add borrowing, like this:

```
return (&query, &filename)
```

But that does not work either;

```
warning: unused variable: `query`
 --> src/main.rs:5:10
  |
5 |     let (query, filename) = parse();
  |          ^^^^^ help: consider prefixing with an underscore: `_query`
  |
  = note: #[warn(unused_variables)] on by default

warning: unused variable: `filename`
 --> src/main.rs:5:17
  |
5 |     let (query, filename) = parse();
  |                 ^^^^^^^^ help: consider prefixing with an underscore: `_filename`

error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:17:17
   |
17 |     let query = args[1];
   |                 ^^^^^^^
   |                 |
   |                 cannot move out of borrowed content
   |                 help: consider borrowing here: `&args[1]`

error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:18:20
   |
18 |     let filename = args[2];
   |                    ^^^^^^^
   |                    |
   |                    cannot move out of borrowed content
   |                    help: consider borrowing here: `&args[2]`

error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `filename`
  --> src/main.rs:20:12
   |
20 |     return (&query, &filename)
   |            ^^^^^^^^^---------^
   |            |        |
   |            |        `filename` is borrowed here
   |            returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `query`
  --> src/main.rs:20:12
   |
20 |     return (&query, &filename)
   |            ^------^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |            ||
   |            |`query` is borrowed here
   |            returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

No clue what is going on or why it does not work, I copied the example straight from the tutorial as well.

Comment: [The duplicate applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=470002f8bde074ada9709524a83f0ea8), but I [wouldn't use `collect` at all](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=617ccdade56b3dd6469f9881d044d203)

Comment: did not realize that this had anything to do with the strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are tricky in rust. First, let's review ["What is Ownership?"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html), ["The Slice Type"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html#string-slices), and ["Lifetime Syntax"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html) from the Rust Book.

The problem is that an `&str` is a borrow (indicated by the `&`) of an object. The rust compiler needs to know how long it will be borrowed for. Now, rust will actually attempt ["lifetime elision"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/error-index.html#E0106), by assuming that the lifetime of the return value will match the lifetime of an input value, but in this case there are no input values, so it can't infer. It needs you to annotate the return type with an lifetime. You *can* use `'static`, but you can also give your function a generic lifetime specifier. Here's a simplified example:

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=adbf65b4c610b83573e50b62e196915a)

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("{}", gimme_str());
}

fn gimme_str() -> &str {
    return "foo";
}
```

That won't compile, either. But all you need to do to get it to compile is to add a lifetime, like so:

[with Lifetime Specifier](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6cb72b0e10b4f7113722fb18fca0b003)

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", gimme_str());
}

fn gimme_str<'a>() -> &'a str {
    return "foo";
}
```

Alternatively, you could let the lifetime be inferred from the input, although in this case that's pretty weird since the input is unused:

[with Lifetime Elision (inferred from input)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2c7dfb05718ef038f586fe6eaed19feb)

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", gimme_str("bar"));
}

fn gimme_str(_input: &str) -> &str {
    return "foo";
}
```

So that's the lifetime specifier. But you have another issue, which is that your return values are slices of strings that are owned by the function. We can demonstrate the error in simplified form by modifying the previous rust playground code (the one with lifetime specifiers):

[can't borrow local variables](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=19804926be9e4056bc6b457875181fe3)

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", gimme_str());
}

fn gimme_str<'a>() -> &'a str {
    let foo = String::from("foo");
    return &foo;
}
```

A borrow is always a borrow *of* something. In the previous example code, where I used a string literal, the `&str` is a borrow of the *immutable string literal*. That's a part of the rust binary the compiler generates, and the `&str` can just point to that part of the binary. You can think of the underlying memory as being "owned" by the binary itself, meaning that it never goes out of scope (i.e., the lifetime of a string literal is `'static`).

However, in the modified example, `&foo` is a borrow not of a string literal, but of a `String` object. That `String` object is assigned to a local variable, so its owner is the owner of that variable -- the function. That means that it will go out of scope and be dropped when the function exits. But once the `String` object no longer exists, it's not valid to borrow it.

In order for the `String` to live beyond the scope of the function, we have to return the `String` itself, so that ownership is transferred to the caller. We can't just return a borrow. See example code:

[transferring ownership from a function](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cd0401ccfbecb0bb0d742bc7f2fea0f7)

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", gimme_str());
}

fn gimme_str() -> String {
    let foo = String::from("foo");
    return foo;
}
```

To apply that to your case, you're going to have to return `String` from your function, not `&str`.

Comment: Thanks. In the line in `parse`, `let query = args[1];`, does this mean that `query` is a reference?

Comment: What shows that `query` is a reference is the doc for [std::ops::Index](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html#tymethod.index), which is the trait that allows you to write `args[1]`. The return type for the `index` method (`[index]` is syntactic sugar) is `&Self::Output`, which is indeed a reference.